# Installation of Lubuntu 14.04 fails on PowerPC iMac G3 "mount: can't find /run in /etc/fstab"

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, mac, powerpc

I am trying to install Lubuntu on an iMac g3 because OS 9 stinks and that is about the only way to make one of these wastes of plastics useful.  I burned a disk with the power pc version of Trusty Tahr, but after a few walls of text and white screens it displays this: mount: can't find /run in /etc/fstab and restarts in 2 minutes. I tried this multiple times burning two different disks. please help me, and thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

That is [bug #1341334 - Installation of Lubuntu 14.04 fails on PowerPC computer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1341334).

Comment: is there some way to work around it?

Comment: Not that I know of. Someone with affected hardware needs to figure out what is going wrong and how to fix it. You could ask in the Launchpad bug if anyone has had any luck figuring it out.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, after tons of coasters I was able to get xubuntu 6.04 on it and I haven't touched it since.